# Formik yup validate one field if another is not empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I have profile settings form, where all fields are not required.
Among this fields i have `password` and `confirmNewPassword` field
I need to check that field `confirmNewPassword` matches `password` field and set this filed required(`confirmNewPassword`) only when i'm typing some text in the `password` field

### This is my validation schema

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    firstName: Yup.string()
      .min(3, 'Firstname should be longer than 2 symbols')
      .max(255, 'Firstname should be shorter than 255 symbols')
      .nullable(true)
      .transform((_, value: string) => {
        return value === '' ? null : value
      }),
    lastName: Yup.string()
      .min(3, 'Lastname should be longer than 2 symbols')
      .max(255, 'Lastname should be shorter than 255 symbols')
      .nullable(true)
      .transform((_, value: string) => {
        return value === '' ? null : value
      }),
    email: Yup.string()
      .email('Invalid email format')
      .nullable(true)
      .transform((_, value: string) => {
        return value === '' ? null : value
      }),
    phone: Yup.string()
      .matches(/^[0-9]+$/, 'Must be only digits')
      .min(4, 'Phone should be longer than 3 symbols')
      .max(12, 'Phone should be shorter than 12 symbols')
      .nullable(true)
      .transform((_, value: string) => {
        return value === '' ? null : value
      }),
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(4, 'Password should be longer than 3 symbols')
      .max(30, 'Password should be shorter than 30 symbols')
      .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/, 'Only English letters and numbers')
      .nullable(true)
      .transform((_, value: string) => {
        return value === '' ? null : value
      }),
    confirmNewPassword: Yup.string()
      .when('password', {
        is: (password: string) => password !== '',
        then: Yup.string()
          .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
          .required('Field required, while changing password'),
      })
      .nullable()
      .transform((_, value: string) => {
        return value === '' ? null : value
      }),
  })
```

But i can't change any field now, while i don't type in the `password` and then in the `confirmNewPassword` fields.

### UPD:

Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Remove the null value in the `confirmPassword`.

```js
...
confirmNewPassword: Yup.string()
    .when('password', {
        is: (password: string) => password !== '',
        then: Yup.string()
            .required('Field required, while changing password'),
            .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords must match')

...
```

This is because Password string can have string size [4, 30], this means confirmPassword cannot be null.

Comment: I tried to do this, but it didn't help. Submit button still disables, when i try, for instance, change the `phone` value. Also i tried to remove the `nullable()` from `confirmPassword` and it didn't work too.

Comment: You wrote the same answer with addition of `.oneOf` property to both password fields, which explicitly not required.

Answer (score 0):

### This is working for me:

I've added `.oneOf([Yup.ref('confirmNewPassword')], 'Passwords must match')` in the `password` field and made it 'match each other', so now i can change any value in my form (because i've deleted the 'required' option in `confirmNewPassword`) and if i trying to type anything in the `password` or `confirmNewPassword` field, validation works fine.

### This is my code:

```
 password: Yup.string()
      .min(4, 'Password should be longer than 3 symbols')
      .max(30, 'Password should be shorter than 30 symbols')
      .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/, 'Only English letters and numbers')
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('confirmNewPassword')], 'Passwords must match')
      .nullable(true)
      .transform((_, value: string) => {
        return value === '' ? null : value
      }),
    confirmNewPassword: Yup.string()
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords must match')
      .nullable(true)
      .transform((_, value: string) => {
        return value === '' ? null : value
      })
```

### Hope it will help someone

Comment: You don't have to add `.oneOf` property for both the fields, adding it in any one of them will do the job.